# Intersection of two vectorspaces: row echelon form contradicts solution by inspection

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $ V = \operatorname{span} \lbrace (-1,-1,0,0)^T, (0,0,-1,-1)^T \rbrace $ and $W = \operatorname{span} \lbrace (2,1,0,-1), (-1,0,-1,0) \rbrace$.
Then $V \cap W$ is a 1-dimensional space, spanned by the vector $(1,1,-1,-1)^T$ (this is the solution by inspection).

On the other hand, to compute the intersection of two spaces via linear algebra, we form the matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 
-1 & 0 & 2 & -1 \\ 
-1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\ 
0 & -1 & -1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}.$$
This row reduces to the matrix (done by hand or via computational algebra)
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\  
  & 1 & 0 & 1 \\  
  &   & 1 & -1 \\  
  &   &   & 0 
\end{pmatrix}.$$
We can read off a spanning vector of the intersection from the above RREF, $(-1, 1, -1, -1)^T$. This clearly isn't a multiple of the vector found by inspection. What went wrong?

Comment: Looks like you have put all the vectors as columns of a matrix and then found a basis for the kernel of the matrix. Why do you think this will give us a basis for $V\cap W$?

Comment: Is this not just the linear algebra aspect? We want vectors $v$ which satisfy $v = a v_1 + bv_2 = cw_1 + dw_2$, so we can form a matrix equation $A \cdot (a, b, c, d)^T = 0$ - then to find $a, b, c, d$ we simply need the kernel of $A$, which is read off its RREF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
As alluded to in a comment reply, I was solving for coefficients $a, b, c, d$ for which $v = av_1 + bv_2 = cv_1+dv_2$, but I mistakenly took it as the vector $(a,b,c,d)^T$ spanning the intersection, as opposed to either $av_1 + bv_2$ or $cv_1+dv_2$ spanning the intersection.

Comment: Half of those $v_i$ should be $w_i$, and then your answer to your own question will very closely resemble the answer to your question that I posted 2.5 hours earlier.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your answer as written, and I found out the issue on my own with my question - thanks for the addition though!

Answer (score 0):

You should have row reduced an augmented matrix, with a zero column appended on the right.

The solution has one free variable. If we let $x_4=-1$, then a solution is $(-1,1,-1,-1)$, which means that:

$$-1v_1+1v_2-1w_1-1w_2=\mathbf{0}$$

So

$$-1v_1+1v_2=-\left(-1w_1-1w_2\right)$$

Which is exactly the solution you found by inspection.

Comment: Doesn't row reducing an augmented matrix with a zero column on the right result in the same matrix I produced?

Comment: Yes, but I meant the interpretation: you are solving for a nontrivial linear combination of the vectors that results in $\mathbf{0}$, because that would imply a vector in both subspaces.